# Nodejs - User Data on login to front-end

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, authentication

I have build a couple other expressjs applications, but I just can't find how to pass the User Model to the front-end or put it in the req as a parameter.

The app is a one page web app, so the user uses the login form to post to /login:

```
app.post('/login', require('./app/controllers/user').login);
```

the controller picks it up and calls the specific module in order to handle the request:

```
exports.login = function (req,res) {
  AccountHandler.login(req,function (response) {
    if (response.code < 0) {
      req.flash('error', response.msg);
    }
    else if (response.code > 0) {
      req.flash('success', response.msg);
    }
    req.user = response.user;
    res.redirect(response.url);
  });
}
```

and here is the module handling the login and calling the callback by passing the required arguments:

```
exports.login = function (req,callback) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
      User.findOne({ 'valid.email': req.body.Email }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) {
            callback({url: '/#login', msg: "There was an unexpected error!", code: -10});
          }
          if (!user) {
            callback({url: '/#login', msg: "No such email/password combination was found", code: -1});
          }
          if (user) {
            easyPbkdf2.verify(user.valid.salt, user.valid.password, req.body.Password, function (err, valid) {
              if (!valid){
                callback({url: '/#login', msg: "No such email/password combination was found", code: -1});
              }
              else{
                callback({user: user, url: '/', msg: "acknowledged", code: 10});
              }
            });
          }
      });
  });
}
```

In the Controller I am saying `req.user = response.user;` which doesn't persist, and when the user is redirected to '/' the req.user is still empty. how can I keep this user information to the redirect page?

Comment: Why u don't pass the user id as url parameter ?

Comment: I dont want to be using url params. I am thinking now maybe i can pass it through middleware using the session.user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to use session + middleware logic/functionality.

Here is the setup (exrepssjs):

Using the express-session module:

```
var sessionMiddleware = session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  httpOnly: true,
  genid: function(req) {
     return uuid.v1() // I used another module to create a uuid
  },
  secret: 'random secret here',
  cookieName: 'session', // if you dont name it here it defaults to connectsid
});
```

following create a middleware, so that you process the session on every request as follows (simplified, i do a lookup on the user overtime and pass it back to the front end):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_messages = req.flash('success_messages');
  res.locals.error_messages = req.flash('error_messages');

  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
    User.findOne({ email: req.session.user.email }, function(err, user) {
      if (user) {
        req.user = user;
        delete req.user.password; // delete the password from the session
        req.session.user = user;  //refresh the session value
        res.locals.user = user;
      }
      // finishing processing the middleware and run the route
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Now from the front-end most of the time using either ejs or jade you can access the user using the "user" variable.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, the res.redirect() call will actually cause the
browser to redirect to the given url, which will result in a new request to
your express server. Since its a new request, the old req object is no longer 
relevant.
I think what you want is to store the logged in user's session using express session middleware. Lots of good examples are out there.. Here is [one](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions).

Comment: Ye i thought of that also a bit late (after i wrote the question) will give it a go tomorrow and post an example if i make it